# How to create a series using For loop.?

Tags: series-expansion, infinite-loop, education

i want to create a series such as 10^n-1 * 10^n-2 *.......... * 10^2 * 10^1 using for loop ; here is my code.

```
  For[n=1, n<18, a=10^n; n++, b=(10^n)*a;];
```

whether this is the right way, or not.?
i assume that in the start (n=1),   **a** will be evaluated , and then increment due to n++ occurs in  the value of n that is n becomes (n=2) , and then the value of b will be evaluated, and so on, 
means to say that the odd values of n will be used in the evaluation of a, and the even values evaluate the b.
Thanks in advance

Comment: so if you know how to do this tell me, instead of treating it like a joke.

Comment: please help me.

Comment: Dear i am new to this software, previously i worked on Wein2k software, but now for some analytical solution i am using MATHEMATICA  .

Comment: if there is another method kindly share it

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What's the significance of `a` and `b` and the odd/even values of `n`?

Comment: @M.MUmber, copy the code from my comment and run in notebook (with Shift-Enter). You will see what you get and understand if it is right. If not - change the code and run again. I provided  you with the [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) where you will find many alternative ways of doing the same task. But you should play around with all of them. And edit you question to provide the result that you want to get.

Comment: Please see answers left below. Also, refer to the folowing post in future: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396. In particular section describing how to avoid using Procedural loops.

Answer (score 2):

in *Mathematica* using a list, and functions that manipulate lists, is better than using loops: for , do , while ... . 
But you can do this, with both of them, and also with "definite product" from Basic Math Assistant palette. (Calculus Commands tab on the Palettes menu -> Basic Math Assistant -> Basic Commands).

With the palette:

[image: product]

With a loop:

```
a = 1; For[n = 1, n <= 18, n++, a *= 10^n]
```

With a function:

```
f[n_] := 10^n
Product[f[n], {n, 1, 10}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see example below:

`Table[(10^i)*10^i, {i, 18}]`

**Reference:**
[Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)